# how do I re-seed a table to 0 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

This does not work:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('[DMS].[dbo].[ImportedFiles]', RESEED, 0)
```

Once the next record gets inserted, I want the seed to be 0 not 1.

I tried this but the function doesn't like it:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('[DMS].[dbo].[ImportedFiles]', RESEED, -1)

DBCC CHECKIDENT('[DMS].[dbo].[ImportedFiles]', RESEED, '-1')
```

How do I reset the seed of a table so that the next record that goes in is a ZERO? (0)?

Comment: @ebyrob why should 0 be invalid? What if I start at -10, should SQL Server skip 0 when it gets there?

Comment: Generally speaking a 0th record is usually a special one that would indicate a non value. In circumstances where I want to have a 0th record for this purpose, I manually insert by enabling identity inserts then turn it off again.

Comment: @ebyrob please find me documentation for any database that considers 0 to be an invalid value in any context, never mind one that will skip 0 just because.

Comment: 0 in this table = "UNKNOWN" ... I have a process that automatically populates this table, starting with 0 = unknown.

Comment: @ebyrob you shouldn't extrapolate the problems you had with an `IDENTITY` column in MySQL without knowing if those problems also exists in SQL Server

Comment: My older brother was killed by a zero in MySQL

Comment: What on earth does "doesn't like it" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, could you tell us that, instead of your synopsis of how the function felt about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the IDENTITY column is defined as (0,1), and the table is empty, and there are no foreign keys involved, just issue:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.ImportedFiles;
```

If the table has foreign keys - or in any event, for that matter - you can just override the value:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedFiles ON;
INSERT dbo.ImportedFiles(col1, col2) SELECT 0, 'UNKNOWN';
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ImportedFiles OFF;
```

I have confirmed that [@Avarkx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21147849/61305) also works - reseed with -1 should yield a next insert of 0. So I'm not sure what version you're using where this doesn't work (I have no idea how to interpret "doesn't like it").

Answer (score 5):

I can't replicate this...  Here's a test that works, SQL Server 2012. 2008 R2.

Also, @Anybody saying 0 means something, it really doesn't.  While it's fairly common to see 0 values being used as unknowns and the like, business logic built around an IDENTITY column is an anti-pattern which generally should be avoided and definitely never recommended.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo
(
    Foo_PK BIGINT IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
    Bar BIT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Foo (Bar)
    SELECT b.Bar
    FROM 
        (SELECT Bar = NULL
         UNION ALL  
         SELECT Bar = 1
         UNION ALL  
         SELECT Bar = 0) b;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Foo;

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.Foo', RESEED, -1);

INSERT INTO dbo.Foo (Bar)
    SELECT  b.Bar
    FROM 
        (SELECT Bar = NULL
         UNION ALL  
         SELECT Bar = 1
         UNION ALL  
         SELECT Bar = 0) b;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Foo;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Foo;
```

Comment: "while it's common to see 0 values being used as unknowns and the like, business logic built around an IDENTITY column is an anti-pattern." This. I'm trying to break a large client of this habit (both software and DB folks habitually assume an ID of 0 is invalid without any testing or analysis). It's so difficult and frustrating when related bugs arise and the response is "They just shouldn't use 0 as the ID."

Comment: @ebyrob What? I didn't say anything about that either way, all I did was remark on how relatable I found Avarkx's comment about automatically treating zero valued IDs as special cases. In the SQL Server / .Net world, it's a nasty and unfortunately common (or maybe I just need better clients?) anti-pattern.

Comment: @ebyrob I would expect such complete rebuilds to be harder if you're relying on `WHERE  a.FK = 1` instead of just doing the correct joins and `WHERE  a.Code = 'UNKNOWN'` equivalent...